# I have a proof concerning prime numbers. Should I publish my result?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, prime-gaps

I can easily and shortly prove that given $ε$, computable using all primes less than $N$, there will be at least one prime number between $n$ and $(1+ε)n$, where $n > N$.

It proves Bertrand's Postulate for $ε = 1$. And it gives a better result for $ε < 1$.

So my questions are:

- Is this result notable?
- Should I publish it?
- If so, where and how?

Thanks for your answers/comments.

Comment: This is already known: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate, the "Better results" section, first paragraph. The citation is to Hardy and Wright.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Yes you are right it's already known. But it says only that  "there is a N > 0 such that".... I have an equation that computes that N!!! And every year someone else finds some smaller ε...

Comment: At the very least, you should look up the reference and see whether it gives the same proof.

Comment: @user1582006 Did you show your proof someone else?

Comment: @BrightChancellor NO! I don't know someone who can help me.

Comment: @user1582006 Well, you said have an easy and short proof, I think it is interesting. If there is not any major gap in your argument or proof is not false, you can send it to a journal for publication.

Comment: You have posted the same question on AcademiaSE : https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/103593/i-have-a-proof-concerning-prime-numbers-should-i-publish-my-result. I think Dan Romik's answer on your first AcademiaSE applies just as well with your new result, since all in all the situation is the same.

Answer (score 5):

It is hard to evaluate a statement that makes extensive use of the *principle of elimination of quantifiers* - in the sense of "I don't write the quantifiers, and you deal with it" -; however, in the information you've provided there is a passage, right in the beginning, that stands out:

> [...] **given** $\varepsilon$, **computable** using all primes less than $N$, there will be [...]

*Ah*. So the meticulous reader should understand that $\varepsilon$ is not actually *given* (as in a statement which begins with "$\forall \varepsilon$"), but rather *dependent on* $N$, as in $$\forall N,\exists \varepsilon(N),\cdots$$

Such a statement alone does not allow to consider the case $\varepsilon=1$, because as far as you know $\varepsilon(N)$ may never be smaller than $2000$.

In principle, one may argue whether the statement proceeds with "$\forall n>N$" or "$\exists n>N$"; however, since the latter gives a trivial theorem, let's assume that we're facing: $$\forall N,\exists\varepsilon(N),\forall n>N,\exists p(\varepsilon(N),n)\text{ prime},\ n<p(\varepsilon(N),n)<(1+\varepsilon(N))n$$

This looks like [the theorems linked by user Patrick Stevens in the comments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results), but it's actually not the same thing: those results should rather be phrased as (refinements of) $$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists N(\varepsilon),\forall n>N(\varepsilon),\exists p(\varepsilon,n)\text{ prime},\ n<p(\varepsilon,n)<(1+\varepsilon)n$$ which is **stronger** than your claim. Specifically, it can be recovered from yours only by *further* showing that there is some choice of $\varepsilon$ such that $\lim_{N\to\infty}\varepsilon(N)=0$: if that's the case, you can select $N(\varepsilon)=\min\{ M\in\Bbb N\,:\, \varepsilon(M)<\varepsilon\}$.

Comment: +1 for the principle of elimination of quantifiers (although it's worth noting that there's a [different version out there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_elimination)).